# Problems with Pass-by-Reference in ObjC

Tags: objective-c

I wanna do pass by reference in ObjC. 
Here is the illustration of the scenario:

```
// MainClass.h
@interface MainClass
{
    Board *board;
    OtherClass *other;
}
@end

// MainClass.m
@implementation MainClass

- (id)init
{
   if (self = [super init])
   {
      board = [[Board alloc] init];
      other = [[OtherClass alloc] initOtherClassWithBoard: board];
   }
   return self
}

@end

// Other class.h
@interface OtherClass
{
   Board *refBoard;
}
- (void)initOtherClassWithBoard: (Board*)ref;
@end

@implementation OtherClass

- (id)initOtherClassWithBoard: (Board*)ref
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
       refBoard = ref;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

So my question is does my OtherClass is holding a reference Board from MainClass?
Or OtherClass's Board is a copy but not a reference.
If I wanna do a reference then how should I change it?

EDIT:
What if I add this on both classes

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Board *board;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *always* refer to objects in Objective-C via pointers, a.k.a. references. Therefore, objects are *always* passed by reference in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

It's a reference.  It won't be a copy unless you do something to make it a copy (like use `@property (copy)` or send it a `copy` message).

Comment: how about if I do this?
@property (nonatomic, retain) ?

Comment: @CadrickLoh - `@property (nonatomic, retain)` does not create a copy of the object. `nonatomic` has to do with how the properties are accessed, google or search StackOverflow for more info. `retain` increases the retain count of the object.